# laravel-3 core exception on new installation

Tags: laravel, laravel-3

I have a new installation of Laravel on a machine running ubuntu 12.04 LTS, Nginx, php-cgi, and Laravel v3.2.14

I am getting the following error.

**Unhandled Exception**

**Message:**
Undefined index: argv

**Location:**
DOCUMNET ROOT/laravel/core.php on line 218

EDIT:

I have managed to get a slightly more descriptive error by commenting out the error handling function in laravel //Error::shutdown(); on line 50 of DOCUMENT ROOT/laravel/laravel.php

Note that this line does not cause the error, it only seems to register a handler for the code that does.

Here is the error:

**Unhandled Exception**

**Message:**
A driver must be set before using the session.

**Location:**
DOCUMENT ROOT/laravel/session.php on line 109

**Stack Trace:**

1. DOCUMENT ROOT/laravel/session.php(150): Laravel\Session::instance()
2. DOCUMENT ROOT/laravel/laravel.php(195):
   Laravel\Session::__callStatic('save', Array)
3. DOCUMENT ROOT/laravel/laravel.php(195): Laravel\Session::save()
4. DOCUMENT ROOT/public/index.php(34): require('/mona/developme...')
5. {main}

These are the code blocks causing the error:

```
if (Config::get('session.driver') !== '')
{
    Session::save();
}
```

Which calls this function in DOCUMENT ROOT/laravel/session.php

```
public static function __callStatic($method, $parameters)
{
    return call_user_func_array(array(static::instance(), $method), $parameters);
}
```

$method contains the string 'save', and $parameters is an empty array.

Comment: tbh I'm a little confused. You say it's on core 218 (argv issue), then you paste two code blocks that have nothing to do with that line.

I just updated my core to latest, no problems. I do have to wonder if maybe it's an nginx/php-cgi issue (try using php-fpm, it's better anyways) - and perhaps that part of the server vars is not passed along.

Comment: I tracked the errors down to those code blocks after commenting out "Error::shutdown();" on line 50 of laravel.php.  I would love to switch everything over to php-fpm, this is a corporate issue that is out of my hands though.

Comment: @Oddman I updated the question to clearly show the logic.  And thank you for your response.

Comment: ah damn - glad you got it sorted, though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel thinks that it is being accessed by cli if you are using php-cgi.

The solution is Modifying DOCUMENT ROOT/laravel/request.php like this:

```
public static function cli()
{
    // This is a hack to make laravel work with fast-cgi
    // Added by David - 03/27/13
    if(!array_key_exists('argv', $_SERVER)) return false;

    return defined('STDIN') || (substr(PHP_SAPI, 0, 3) == 'cgi' && getenv('TERM'));

}
```

Checking if the $_SERVER super global has the 'argv' key before returning false permits cli to continue to function while using php-cgi.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by your answer, this worked for me:

```
public static function cli()
{
    if(array_key_exists('HTTP_HOST', $_SERVER)) return false;

    return defined('STDIN') || (substr(PHP_SAPI, 0, 3) == 'cgi' && getenv('TERM'));
}
```